# TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, loops, google-apps-script

I keep running to **Cannot find function for each in object** error while trying to loop entries. Is there something I am not seeing?. Here the code. This code is supposed to fetch time data from a system via API do calculations and send email

```
function getTime() {
    var range = [5323, 9626, 4998];
    var user = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {

        var auth = 'token'

        var from = '2020-01-08'
        var to = '2020-01-09'
        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + range[i] + '/time_entries?from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&auth=' + auth;

        var options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth
            }
        };

        var submitted_time_entries = {};
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        var time_entries = response.data;

        time_entries.forEach(function (time_entry) {
            if (time_entry.user_id in submitted_time_entries) {
                submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] += time_entry.hours;
            } else {
                submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] = time_entry.hours;
            }
        });

        submitted_time_entries.forEach(function (user_id) {
            if (submitted_time_entries[user_id] < 3) {
                //send mail
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `forEach()` not `foreach()`, note the camel casing.

Comment: @ross Thanks for flagging this. I have changed the casing but still, get an error **Cannot find function forEach in object [object Object].** Look at my edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my  API returned an object. I figured out the way around it by using **Object.keys** method and it worked. Here is the working code.

```
function getTime() {
    var range = [53, 926, 8098];
    var user = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {

        var auth = 'token';

        var from = '2020-01-08'
        var to = '2020-01-09'
        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + '449625' + '/time_entries?from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&auth=' + auth;

        var options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth
            }
        };

        var submitted_time_entries = {};
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        var time_entries = response.data;


        Object.keys(time_entries).forEach(function (time_entry) {
            if (time_entry.user_id in submitted_time_entries) {
                submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] += time_entry.hours;
            } else {
                submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] = time_entry.hours;
            }
        });

        Object.keys(submitted_time_entries).forEach(function (user_id) {
            if (submitted_time_entries[user_id] < 3) {
                Logger.log(time_entry)
                //send mail
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`response.data` is probably not the array you expect. The server may be returning an error or a successful response that isn't parseable as an array. To find out, print `response.data` to the console and confirm it's the array you expect.

Comment: Hey @spork thanks for the input. I used  Object.keys()  method that returns an array of the keys of an object and it worked. This is how that part of the code looks like now: **Object.keys(time_entries).forEach(function (time_entry) {**

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like your API returns an object instead of an array, which is why you were getting the error.

Comment: It appears so. Thanks for taking the time to look at the code